# How to scale bitmap in FontForge without changing the resolution in pixels?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I have font with resolution 40x40 pixels and I want to have resolution 39x27 pixels. How can I do that?
Maybe is another way to do this than fontforge?

I have tried do Element -> Transformations -> Glyph Origin / Center of Selection -> Scale and then set X 60 %, Y 90 %, but it doesn't scale the letter, only the frame the letter is in. This make letter too big for my resolution.